# Split array of strings into a matrix of numeric digits

Tags: matlab

I want to convert n integers to base b, and write every digit as a single number in a matrix.

I get the base b representation with:

```
stringBaseB=dec2base(0:1:1000,b,10)
```

but don't know how to split every string into a single char

```
[[0,0,0,0];[0,0,0,1];[0,0,0,2];...]
```

I can use array2table to split the individual characters:

```
tableBaseB=array2table(dec2base(stringBaseB,b,10))
```

but that's not a numeric matrix. Also, in base b>10 I get alphanumeric characters, which I need to convert to numeric by an equivalence like

```
alphanumeric=["1","A","c","3"]
numericEquivalence=[1,1+i,-3,0]
```

There is a vectorized way to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For some base `b < 11`, where the character array from `dec2base` is always going to be single-digit numeric characters, you can simply do

```
b = arrayfun( @str2double, stringBaseB );
```

For some generic base `b`, you can make a map between the characters and the values (your `numericEquivalence`)

```
charMap = containers.Map( {'1','2','3'}, {1,2,3} );
```

Then you can use `arrayfun` (not strictly "vectorized" as you requested but it's unclear why that's a requirement)

```
stringBaseB=dec2base(0:1:1000,b,10);
b = arrayfun( @(x)charMap(x), stringBaseB );
```

This gives you a numeric output array, for example `stringBaseB=dec2base(0:5,3,10)` gives

```
stringBaseB =
  6×10 char array
    '0000000000'
    '0000000001'
    '0000000002'
    '0000000010'
    '0000000011'
    '0000000012'

b =
  6x10 double array
     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0
     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     1
     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     2
     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     1     0
     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     1     1
     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     1     2
```

Comment: I made a solution using a for...end, but is unbearably slow. I ask for vectorized because I read that vectorized is always faster.